# Post backend generation

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

I've followed [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.dk/2013/06/adding-backend-to-your-app-in-android.html) blog post and have successfully generated a backend for my project. But that resulted in quite a lot of code.

I have worked with GCM and Endpoints (in python) before. But putting this all together (with java) is a bit hard to comprehend.

Could someone be kind enough to give a brief tutorial on how to build upon this code?

Say I want to add a news sending feature (or whatever). How would I add that to both server and client? Possible ignoring auth.

Answer (score 1):

there are plenty of tutorial in the web, it is true that being so new I have to say that it is not clear at all when you go deeper, but with some time you finally get it.
For personal purposes I created this [blog](http://sca09.blogspot.com/) with the very basic steps that I am learning by myself. Feel free to ask, we are all in the same page at this time.

Comment: I wouldn't say plenty. At least not much taking the subject past hello world. I'll read you blog post in details later on. Thanks for informing me about it.

Comment: Ok, yes, you are right, not so many. In my case I still feel it is not unified and you can create the enpoints from an already existing Android Project, but the result is not 100% the same than if you start from a Google App Engine project and then import the endpoints to a new Android App. I am dealing with this now...